# Loop in each group with dplyr for creating a stepwise curve

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, curve

The **problem**:
I am working with a dataframe as the following which represent bids and offers:

```
PERIOD  CURVETYPE  QUANTITY  PRICE  CURVE_ID
1       SUPPLY     100       0      1
1       DEMAND     500       3000   2
1       SUPPLY     300       63     1
1       DEMAND     200       2900   2
1       SUPPLY     500       52     1
2       DEMAND     700       2800   3
2       DEMAND     100       3000   3
2       SUPPLY     900       73     4
...
```

The CURVE_ID column represents the ID the identity of the curve: demand/supply for each period.  What I want is to build each curve as a STEPWISE curve (with steps),which means:

1. order from price lower to higher
2. cumsum (aggregate the quantity) in Q
3. Create points which represent the STEP (marked with *)

For example, for CURVE_ID=1:

```
   PERIOD  CURVETYPE  QUANTITY    Q       PRICE  CURVE_ID
   1       SUPPLY     100         100     0      1
*  1       SUPPLY     100         100     52     1
   1       SUPPLY     500         600     52     1
*  1       SUPPLY     500         600     63     1
   1       SUPPLY     300         900     63     1

...
```

The first and second point I got to do them. The problem is when dealing with the third point. 
I created a code to create another dataframe with these points market with *, and it works for light data. However, when dealing with heavier data it takes to long and does not work. 
The code is the following:

```
#Cumsum to aggregate the quantity
data_frame <- filter(original_data, CURVETYPE=="SUPPLY") %>% group_by(CURVE_ID) %>% arrange(PRICE, Q) %>% mutate(QUANTITY=cumsum(Q))
data_rbind <- data_frame[1,] #Here Im going to stick my data_frame with the new points

for(i in data_frame$CURVE_ID)){
  data <- filter(data_frame, CURVE_ID==i)
  data %>% arrange(QUANTITY)
  for(j in 1:nrow(data)){
    if (data[j,"PRICE"]!=max(data$PRICE)){
      data[j,"PRICE"]=data[j+1,"PRICE"]
    }
  }
  data_rbind <- rbind(data_rbind,data)
  rm(data)
}
```

I'am sure that it must be a way to do this with group_by of dplyr. 
I have created a function:

```
f<- function(q,p){
  maxPrice <- max(p)
  for (i in 1:nrow()){
    if (i!=which(p==maxPrice)){
      p[i] <- p[i+1]
    }
  }
}
data_frame <- data_frame %>% group_by(CURVE_ID) %>% f(Q,PRICE)
```

But I get the error:

> Error in f(., Q, PRICE) : unused argument (PRICE)

Comment: I want something as the second code in my question :)

Comment: Welcome SO. How do you get to your desired result? It looks as if you may have used different data than the presented data? Please could you adjust your sample data, ideally using an inbuilt data set or `dput` your data

Comment: Anyways. `your_dataframe %>% ungroup()%>% mutate(new_val = match(Q, unique(Q)))` might help

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you are looking for?  It requires `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
df %>% filter(CURVETYPE == "SUPPLY") %>% 
  group_by(CURVE_ID) %>% 
  arrange(PRICE, QUANTITY) %>% 
  mutate(Q = cumsum(QUANTITY),
         endPrice = lead(PRICE)) %>%                    #add price at end of step
  fill(endPrice) %>%                                    #fill NA final value
  gather(key = key, value = PRICE, PRICE, endPrice) %>% #convert price cols to long format
  select(-key) %>%                                      #remove start/end distinction
  distinct() %>%                                        #remove duplicated last rows of group
  arrange(CURVE_ID, Q)

  PERIOD CURVETYPE QUANTITY CURVE_ID     Q PRICE
   <int> <chr>        <int>    <int> <int> <int>
1      1 SUPPLY         100        1   100     0
2      1 SUPPLY         100        1   100    52
3      1 SUPPLY         500        1   600    52
4      1 SUPPLY         500        1   600    63
5      1 SUPPLY         300        1   900    63
6      2 SUPPLY         900        4   900    73
7      2 SUPPLY         900        4   900    NA
```

Comment: This is PERFECT. Thank you!